# Find and exec command in linux. Is it possible to pipe 2 find and exec commands

Tags: linux

I'm trying to accomplish this task

1) Find directory A (DIR_A) and copy all files in the directory(including its sub-directory, if any) into a new directory called DIR_B

2) In directory (DIR_B),replace the word apple with orange

I executed the following code and for some reason, it copies all the files but it fails on the second task (replace apple with orange). I would appreciate help on this. Below is my code

```
find DIR_A -iname FILEA -type f -exec cp {} DIR_B \;|find DIR_B/ -iname \*.* -type f -exec sed -i "s|apple|orange|g" {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to piping the output from one find into the other, why not just run them sequentially?  I'm not sure that `find` reads from its stdin.

```
find DIR_A -iname FILEA -type f -exec cp {} DIR_B \; ; find DIR_B/ -iname \*.* -type f -exec sed -i "s|apple|orange|g" {} \;
```

I've replaced your pipe with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
Sed Syntax :
**sed 's/old/new/g'**

```
 find DIR_A -iname FILEA -type f -exec cp {} DIR_B \;|find DIR_B/ -iname \*.* -type f -exec sed -i "s/apple/orange/g" {} \;
```

Comment: I don't think changing the | to / on the sed syntax will have any effect on the outcome. Thanks for your input